# React errors with `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` when having shared library node_modules present

Tags: reactjs, npm, rollupjs

I'm developing a react app with MaterialUI in a monorepo together with a shared component library. I want to develop shared components using MUI, but I'm having some trouble getting the project setup correctly. Currently everything appears to work as long as the shared library has no `node_modules` directory present. If it does, I'm getting the following error when launching the react app.

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

I read that this might be caused by react picking up the installed dependencies from my linked shared library, which I had added to the project via `npm link ../shared_lib`, and that I should install it from a relative path instead. So I `npm install ../shared_lib`'d it instead, but I'm having the exact same issue.

I've of course tried nuking the app's `node_modules` and my lock files, but I still find it curious that `npm link` and `npm install` add the exact same line (`"shared_lib": "file:../shared_lib"`) to my `package.json`. I assume `npm link` creates a symlink in `node_modules` instead of a copy though, but I don't know about the details.

Regarding project setup, my shared library has react/mui listed as dev and peer dependencies, no direct dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
  "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  ...
},
"peerDependencies": {
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
  "@mui/material": "^5.13.6",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
}
```

The main project has the same dependencies and versions listed as direct dependencies.

I'm using rollup to build the shared library, this is the entire rollup config.

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss({ plugins: [] }),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];
```

I was under the assumption that the peer-deps-external-plugin would very likely help here, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the intention. Web development is unfortunately still rather new to me.

I would love to be able to work on both projects at the same time, having a storybook running inside the shared library and running the main application as well, but currently I have to delete the shared library's `node_modules` directory to successfully build the main application, which is not a great developer experience, being able to resolve this would be fantastic.